# Why I am taken to grub4dos when selecting Ubuntu from the boatloader menu?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, bootloader

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 64x alongside Windows 7 (Ubuntu after Windows 7) on my laptop. Ubuntu installed properly without any errors. When I booted the first time, I didn't see grub menu which should have come by default as Ubuntu overwrites winloader. Instead I saw Windows boot menu, which did not have an Ubuntu entry. So I added Ubuntu to the menu from Windows using easyBCD. I started seeing Ubuntu in the menu.

No problem till here. But when I select Ubuntu from the menu, I am taken to the grub4dos prompt. After a lot of research on the web I found a way to boot into Ubuntu using commands. This is what I do everytime to boot into Ubuntu:

```
>root (hd0,4)
>kernel /boot/vmlinuz* root=/dev/sda5 ro
>initrd /boot/init*
>boot
```

Then I found that such problem occurs due to corrupt grub and used the method here to restore it but no use

Does anyone know why I am taken to grub4dos on selecting Ubuntu from the menu or at least how to run a shell script (containing the above commands) from grub4dos so that I don't have to rewrite those commands repeatedly.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: Yes, I am still in search for an answer. Do I post the exact question again @blueXrider ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Solved using 'boot-repair' finally :) Thanks.